# IonicModal: $scope.ionicModal.show() not working after calling $scope.ionicModal.remove()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic modal. When I click this for the first time

```
<label class="list card">
<textarea ng-click="newPost(1); content = '' " placeholder="Write here"></textarea></label>
```

This is the new post function

```
// Open our new task modal
  $scope.newPost = function(index) {
       if (index == 1){
        $scope.postModal.show()
       }else {$scope.selectModal.show();}
     // $scope.postModal.show();

  };
        </label>
```

It pops up the ionic modal, then in other to hide and destroy the ionic modal, I click this

```
<button style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px; color: #ff6000" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeNewPost(1);content= '' ">Clear</button>
```

This is the hide and remove function

```
// Close the new task modal
  $scope.closeNewPost = function(index) {
       if (index == 1) {
    $scope.postModal.hide();
      $scope.postModal.remove();
      } else {
          $scope.selectModal.hide();
       }
      //$scope.postModal.hide();
      // $scope.postModal.hide();
  };
```

Now, my challenge is that on clicking this the second time, it never pops up the ionic modal again

```
<label class="list card">
<textarea ng-click="newPost(1); content = '' " placeholder="Write here"></textarea></label>
```

You can take a look at ionic Modal documentation

```
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/
```

Please what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing again because you're removing the modal. The [docs on `ionicmodal`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/) explain that running `remove()` on a modal will:

> Remove this modal instance from the DOM and clean up.

If you just want to hide/show the same modal, use `hide` and `show`. If you want to remove the modal from the dom, use `remove` but then be sure to recreate the modal when you want to show it again.

[Making modals](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/) shows how to create a modal:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('contact-modal.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal
})
```

If you want to call this code from an `ng-click` just place it within a method and attach it to your controller's scope:

```
$scope.createModal = function() {
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('contact-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
       $scope.modal = modal
    })  
}
```

Comment: So basically, how can I recreate it.

Comment: @JnG in the same way you did originally, I edited my answer to show an example.

Comment: Can I embed this ionicModal inside a function/method, so that I can just call it with ng-click after removing it.

Comment: @JnG Sure, but why do you want to remove it each time?

Comment: Okay. Because, I dont want the content in the textarea to persist after hiding the modal, so I decided to remove the modal. Will be glad if you can reflect click button to re-trigger or re-open the modal on your answer

Comment: @JnG Just create a function in your controller's scope and put the modal creation/removal code in that function.